# How to attach iam role to existing redshift cluster using aws cdk code

Tags: amazon-redshift, amazon-iam, aws-cdk

I know that we can add iam role using manage policy in permissions of redshift cluster, but I want to write code instead of using console.

I'm trying to attach a iam role to a existing redshift cluster means created before. So I want cdk code to attach an iam user to a existing cluster.(I want it in typescript)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same problem last week. So right now it is not possible to add a role to an existing Redshift-Cluster that is not written in CDK. You can import the redshiftcluster by attribute, but you can't add a role to it. You can create the role in AWS CDK and attach it manually to the cluster. Otherwise create a new cluster in aws cdk and there you can add the role via code.